# Limited bandwidth using wireless modem

Tags: wifi, adsl

I would like to set up a couple of wireless modems in a mall but limit the access to wireless by 10MB per user.

Is there any good software I can use to manage this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean limit each user's use of your wifi or limit each user's use of the upstream link? Also what device have you got?

Comment: Hi Chopper. Yes, each user's usage of the wifi link would be limited to 10Mb. I would like to do this with any device as many of the shop owners have different devices so I would want to manage this through some software - open source preferably.

Comment: I honestly think you're going to struggle with this to be honest - wifi channels are inherently open and not designed for this type of function. If it had been upstream you would have been in an easier situation but I don't know of any way to do this sorry. Perhaps speak to Cisco about this requirement, there's a chance they'll have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t26262-how-do-i-limit-the-bandwidth-to-each-user-on-the-wireless-router.html) on the Velocity Reviews forum asks the same question. The posted answer is to either install some software - it mentions http://www.ezlan.net/monitor.html, or use hardware with QQS control.

However, that post is from 2005 so things might have moved on a bit since then.

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit ambiguous, but I'm assuming you mean share a single DSL (or similar) connection wirelessly via a number of wireless access points?

you would have to setup a captive portal of some sort to capture all traffic and force it through a login page to authenticate, and then measure the traffic using a radius server to keep track of total traffic in/out and killing the users connection when it hits a specific limit.

there are a couple of open source ways of doing this, I guess the one that comes to mind is [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) - it's pretty good as a general control firewall and comes bundled with a captive portal (and has a module to install freeradius). Customization will be required, but you can do time and rate limiting out of the box with very little setup.